# How Can I Calculate Distance If Player is Stationary?

Tags: c#, calculator, distance

I'm working on a vertical infinite runner, I'm attempting to grab the distance the player has moved in the y axis but only upwards, I don't want to the distance counter to count down, only up

Since it is a vertical game, jumping is used to get up to platforms, this means that I can't just base the distance counter on how long the player has stayed alive, since they could just stand there while the platforms just drag him down at a constant rate of -27f

I've attempted to just add -27 * Time.deltaTime to my count but that appeared to do absolutely nothing. Below is a counter that is working but only if my player is actually moving upwards, not stationary as I mentioned

```
public class Distance : MonoBehaviour {

    public float distanceCount;

    public Transform playerHeight;

    public Text height;

    public Text shadowHeight;

    void Start () {
        distanceCount = 0;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        distanceCount = (playerHeight.position.y + 0.09500122f) / 200f;

        distanceCount = Mathf.Round(distanceCount * 10f) / 1f;

        height.text = distanceCount.ToString() + " m";

        shadowHeight.text = distanceCount.ToString() + " m";
    }
}
```

If I could get some advice or an update to my current code that might solve for this I would really appreciate it, thank you.

Comment: The way you are describing your issue it sounds like the functionality is working correctly....I dont understand what the problem is can you clarify why you need it to go up if the player is not moving

Comment: Why are you only trying to count down? Does something happen at zero?

Comment: @CoderJoe - I think I didn't explain very well, the game is an infinite runner, so the object of the game is to get the highest distance, so basically I want a way to count my players Y position even though the level is the thing that's moving, the player can jump etc, but the level is dragging him down

How can I count when my player has moved up, but not count when they've been moved downwards, I didn't want to base my distance on time